# Reading a file and storing it in an array, then splitting up the file everywhere there is a },

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to Read a file and store it in an array, then split up the array everywhere there is a }, so that each item in the array contains the string split up. Here is what I mean,

My file contains stuff like this:

```
[
{
    "sample1": {
        "color": "red", 
        "date": "2011, 
        "name": "george"
    }
}, 
{
    "sample2": {
        "color": "red", 
        "date": "2012", 
        "name": "phil"
    }
},
```

I want to read this file, have have for example the oth element in the array to represent

```
{
        "sample1": {
            "color": "red", 
            "date": "2011, 
            "name": "george"
        }
},
```

and for element number one to represent

```
    {
    "sample2": {
        "color": "red", 
        "date": "2012", 
        "name": "phil"
    }
},
```

Now I am not too sure how to do this, I don't know what the size of my array will be and I am not sure how I will access each element of my array, I have started off with this so far

```
String str;
  char[] getArray;

  FileReader fr = new FileReader("/sampleProject");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

  br.readLine();

  while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
     str.toCharArray();
     str.split("},");

  }

  System.out.println("Here it is" + str);

  br.close();
}
```

Comment: Is this JSON? You can try with [JSON in Java](http://json.org/java/).

Comment: The data looks like JSON, do you think it would be better to use a real parser for it?

Comment: I am not too sure, how I would split it with with the json, I am writing the code in java and reading the json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know, what size an array is you can use ArrayList.
`str.toCharArray();` and `str.split("},")};` probably don't do what you expect, since you never asign the returned value.

I didn't test this, but maybe it does what you need:

```
String str;
  char[] getArray;

  FileReader fr = new FileReader("/sampleProject");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

  br.readLine();
  ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

  while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
     String[] array = str.split("},");
     for(int i = 0; i< array.length;i++) {
         result.add(array[i]);
     }
  }

  System.out.println("Here it is" + str);

  br.close();
```

Comment: Why do you copy the result of `split` into an array list? It is already an array of strings that can be accessed directly.

Comment: `array` is a new array for each line in the file. So if you don't copy it, in the end you will only have the last line in your array.

Comment: Good point, but in this solution you print out `str` which is only the last line anyway. @Jack, @Kayz: I still still think this one will give you a misleading result. That's why I use a `StringBuilder` and `append` line by line to get the real full package.

Comment: oh, you're right. I totally forgot about the output in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better parse that JSON into an Object using Jackson Mapper, like this:

```
        import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
        import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
        import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

        public void readJSON(){
            MyBean bean;
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            try {
                bean = mapper.readValue(new File("/sampleProject"), MyBean.class);

            } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

You can get more information about JSON -> Java Objects conversion in: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

You got quite close to it. Just a view things, that are not necessary. If the data is small enough to keep it fully in memory, this would be your code:

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/sampleProject"));

// Read data in
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) data.append(line);

// Split into packages
for(String package : data.toString().split("}")
    System.out.println("Here it is" + package + "}");

br.close();
```

One minor thing is, that the `split` removes the final `}` which you could append again in the `System.println()`.

And yes, it looks like JSON where good JSON Parser exist, e.g. [here](https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/). But if you dont need it...

More relevant is maybe the case, when your data gets too big to keep in memory. You would need to setup a fully streamed solution.